# Switch view set drawables for thumb and track of specific size

Tags: java, android

I am using Switch view and I use my drawable resources for thumb and track.
For now in order to not display text on thumb but have it of specific width i'm doing this: for example, i want thumb width to be 40dp, then i set thumbTextPadding to 20dp. Is there a better way to do it?
There is one more problem i have. I need track width to be exactly 2 * thumb width, but i noticed that switch sets its width to a bit more, and for me this is essential.
Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this i used set the min width styleable for the switch:

```
android:switchMinWidth="40dp"
```

I haven't yet found a way to set the thumb width without using thumbTextPadding.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning thumbTextPadding. This seems to be the only working way to set the width of the thumb to a minimum size.